# How to preview method contents in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, shortcut

Is it possible to preview method contents in PhpStorm? So -fx, I hover a method call and get a small popup window with the method definition. In the popup window I can check whats going on there and just close the popup when Im done.

This would really save some "jump into the method, check whats going on there, go back (even worse if the method was in the same file, so I have to remember the name or position of the method I was working on)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to preview method contents in PhpStorm?

`View | Quick Definition` <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd>

> even worse if the method was in the same file, so I have to remember the name or position of the method I was working on

`Navigate | Back` <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Left</kbd>